# Flask doesn't see the static file

Tags: python, flask

Regards, It's been seeing my static files by now. I am using VS Code as an editor. I clicked accidentally debug mode and then it stopped seeing my static files. I started VS Code again but the result hasn't changed. How can I solve this problem? When I open localhost, it shows *127.0.0.1:5000/static/css/main.css* but it gives an error when I display the page source and open the css file on the new page.

The error I get in the browser is: *TypeError: make_conditional() got an unexpected keyword argument 'accept_ranges'*

The error I received in VS Code is as follows:

```
127.0.0.1 - - [12/Dec/2018 23:17:50] "GET /static/css/main.css HTTP/1.1" 500 -
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 2309, in __call__
    return self.wsgi_app(environ, start_response)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 2295, in wsgi_app
    response = self.handle_exception(e)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 1741, in handle_exception
    reraise(exc_type, exc_value, tb)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/flask/_compat.py", line 35, in reraise
    raise value
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 2292, in wsgi_app
    response = self.full_dispatch_request()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 1815, in full_dispatch_request
    rv = self.handle_user_exception(e)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 1718, in handle_user_exception
    reraise(exc_type, exc_value, tb)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/flask/_compat.py", line 35, in reraise
    raise value
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 1813, in full_dispatch_request
    rv = self.dispatch_request()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 1799, in dispatch_request
    return self.view_functions[rule.endpoint](**req.view_args)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/flask/helpers.py", line 976, in send_static_file
    cache_timeout=cache_timeout)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/flask/helpers.py", line 713, in send_from_directory
    return send_file(filename, **options)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/flask/helpers.py", line 628, in send_file
    complete_length=fsize)
TypeError: make_conditional() got an unexpected keyword argument 'accept_ranges'
```

Comment: If you open up the developer tools of the browser, and check the network tab, do you see your webpage making a request to fetch the .css file? What status code does the request return?

Comment: @mckuok return 500 INTERNAL SERVER ERROR

Comment: version of flask and Werkzeug?

Comment: @mckuok Flask 1.0.2 and Werkzeug==0.11.15

Comment: According to flask, the required  Werkzeug version is `Werkzeug >= 0.14` from [here](http://flask.pocoo.org/docs/1.0/changelog/)

Comment: @mckuok thank you so much

Comment: if the upgrade solves the problem you can select my answer so others can use this as reference for later

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to flask, the required Werkzeug version is Werkzeug >= 0.14 from [here](http://flask.pocoo.org/docs/1.0/changelog/)